# Linking Frameworks into QuickLook plugins

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, dynamic-linking, quicklook

I am trying to write a QuickLook generator. For this, I need to link against a framework I created. However, as soon as I link against said framework, `qlmanage` refuses to load my plugin by telling me:

```
[ERROR] Can't load plug-in at /path/to/my-ql.qlgenerator: The bundle “my-ql” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.
```

I have read all the relevant tutorials on Linking, Frameworks and QuickLook but found no answer.

**Things I have found out/ruled out so far**

- Architecture: when including the Framework as 32-bit binary, the entire linking process faults, so this does not seem to be the problem.
- I have verified that the Framework gets copied into the plugin’s bundle under `Contents/Frameworks`.
- The framework’s install path is set to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`

Also, when using the framework in another application, everything goes well. The only possible explanation I can fathom is as follows: When executing `qlmanage`, the `@executable_path` actually points to that binary and so my framework is never found. If this is the case, how must I set the install path to still allow a location relative to the plugin? I don’t want to install my framework globally.

**EDIT**

`otool -L` on the built QuickLook Plugin yields the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 327.4.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 38.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.29.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/PESHandler.framework/Versions/A/PESHandler (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0) <== *this is my framework*
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
```

`otool -D` on my framework yields this:

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/PESHandler.framework/Versions/A/PESHandler
```

The Framework *does not require* garbage collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@executable_path resolves against the main executable image for the process. That would be the quicklook daemon, not your plug-in. You should use @loader_path instead.

Here's a [blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) covering this.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually read about some of those variables (including `@loader_path` and `@rpath`) but not given it much thought.

Comment: ..ideally switch to `@rpath` as well as suggested by http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if the application in which you used your framework required garbage collection. Nor do you say if your framework requires it. You may be attempting to compile your Quick Look generator using garbage collection. But, "Quick Look generators don't get compiled with garbage collection on," according to [Nicholas Riley's reply to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784474/feedback-on-my-first-objective-c-code-a-quicklook-plugin). This alone may explain why, as you say, "the entire linking process faults," if indeed that's what you're attempting.

Lacking familiarity with your framework, I have no idea how involved the process would be to eliminate reliance on garbage collection (if, again, that's the case), but your framework may require reworking in order to be used in a Quick Look generator.

Comment: No, neither the framework nor the application I tested it with used GC. I have, of course, read all the relevant discussion on SO (and, specifically, the one you linked to). It says, there would be leaks but leaks are not my problem (at least not right now). Also, my comment that “the entire linking process faults” only applies (as I’ve stated) “when including the Framework as 32-bit binary”, so I don’t see how it should be relevant to the question of garbage-collection: when the build architectures of plugin and framework *match*, the linking process, of course, goes through just fine.