# QuickLook PlugIn is "damaged/missing resources". Why?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks, quicklook

**SETUP:**
OS X 10.8.2
Xcode4.5.2 (4G2008a)
Document-based Cocoa Application with a QuickLook PlugIn

---

**PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to add a QuickLook plugin to my Document-based OS X application, but the QL PlugIn will not launch.

My QuickLook PlugIn needs to embed and link to *two Frameworks* that I've created myself (Called `IDEKit` and `TDAppKit`). I've read this [SO post about linking Frameworks in QuickLook PlugIns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750032/linking-frameworks-into-quicklook-plugins), and followed the instructions there (I set the `DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE` of my two Frameworks to `@loader_path/../Frameworks`).

Here's some relevant information about my QuickLook PlugIn after it is built:

```
% otool -L /Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/MacOS/ShapesQuickLook 
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/MacOS/ShapesQuickLook:
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 47.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/TDAppKit.framework/Versions/A/TDAppKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 555.4.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55179.0.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 45.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.11.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1187.33.0)
```

The linked/embedded Frameworks are in place:

```
% file /Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/MacOS/ShapesQuickLook 
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/MacOS/ShapesQuickLook: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/MacOS/ShapesQuickLook (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/MacOS/ShapesQuickLook (for architecture i386):  Mach-O bundle i386
% file /Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit 
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
% file /Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/TDAppKit.framework/TDAppKit 
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/TDAppKit.framework/TDAppKit: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/TDAppKit.framework/TDAppKit (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/Contents/Frameworks/TDAppKit.framework/TDAppKit (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

However, when I try to launch my QuickLook PlugIn using `qlmanage` and a test document, I get the following error:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/Resources/quicklookd.app/Contents/MacOS/qlmanage) is code signed with entitlements
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    /Users/itod/Desktop/test.shapes
[ERROR] Can't load plug-in at file://localhost/Users/itod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shapes-bqzarhutlkqukverhbjatfvaextg/Build/Products/Debug/Shapes.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/ShapesQuickLook.qlgenerator/: The bundle “ShapesQuickLook” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.
```

Note the:

```
The bundle “ShapesQuickLook” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.
```

I'm not certain that this issue is caused by a problem with embedded Frameworks (but I think it probably is).

What might I be missing? How can I get my QuickLook PlugIn to launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP here. I found the solution in this [blog post about Dylibs, Install Names, and rpaths](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html).

Specifically, the advice under the **@rpath** section worked for me.

So in my embedded frameworks, I set the `DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE` to be `@rpath/`.

Then I have an App and a QL PlugIn which each embed the frameworks:

In my Application target's build settings, I added the following *Other Linker Flags*: `-rpath @executable_path/../Frameworks/`.

And in my QuickLook Plugin target's build settings I added the following *Other Linker Flags*: `-rpath @loader_path/../Frameworks/`.

That solved the issue. Now the app and the QL PlugIn work correctly.

Comment: the problem is that the executable name that one normally users really means the executable of the process and for your QL plugin that'd be quicklookd -- can't you se the loader path in both cases?

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue of the executable being different when my app is running vs when my QL plugin is running. But changing to `@loader_path` alone did not fix the issue. I'm not entirely sure why, but I have a theory. Basically: Not only does the Plugin link to both of these frameworks, but one of these frameworks is also linking to the other framework, further complicating matters. Using `@rpath` seems to allow them all to find each other.

Comment: Awesome - same issue here, same steps worked for us as well!!

Comment: Additional great information to be found in http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/